# UserManager.UpdateSecurityStamp reverts user data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I'm using `UpdateSecurityStamp` to logout user from all browsers.

My code is:

```
var userManager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();

            using (var db = new Entities())
            {
                var user = db.AspNetUsers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id.Equals("c0bf0112-c856-4bc9-a29f-0bd28c65bfe9"));
                user.PhoneNumber = "1234"; //old phone number was ""
                db.SaveChanges();
                //phone number is updated in database
            }

            userManager.UpdateSecurityStamp(User.Identity.GetUserId()); //phone number value is reverted
```

**Issue:**
Any value updated before calling `UpdateSecurityStamp` is reverted.
If I go to database and manually updated a column value, its reverted back on calling `UpdateSecurityStamp`. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't figure out why it reverts user data but I found a hack to tackle this.
Instead of calling

```
userManager.UpdateSecurityStamp(userId);
```

use

```
userObject.SecurityStamp = Convert.ToString(Guid.NewGuid());
```

i.e, just update security stamp for a user.